# PHP em produção com composer

Tags: php, composer

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza algumas dependências e essas mesmas geridas pelo o **composer** tudo a funcionar no ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Mas em produção, como é possível instalar uma aplicação **php** com dependências ?

O que é necessito para que tudo funcione em produção ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar:

```
composer.phar install --no-dev
```

ou

```
composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

(ele gera um mapa de classe que acelerará o carregamento automático em seu aplicativo).

Espero ter ajudado.